# Is it possible to render ComponentPresentation into another ComponentPresentation so that the contents will appear in the page?

Tags: componentpresentation, component

I am new to Tridion. I am asking how to render ComponentPresentation into another ComponentPresentation so that the contents will appear in the page. I have this [image] written on the template building block of the main component hoping to render the contents of the second one. I often have error in publishing the page. How should this be done? Thank you.

Comment: In principle it should be possible to do something like this, but the signature of `RenderComponentPresentation` is `public string RenderComponentPresentation(string componentUri, string templateUri)`, so it expects two strings representing Component and Template TCM URI.  What error do you get? Please check the Tridion Event Log for detailed error info.

Comment: Welcome to Tridion Stack Exchange! As a quick tip, the Content Manager reports errors that come from templating typically as "rendering" issue. You can also check which Pages would have an issue during publishing by _previewing_ the Page with the problematic Page Template in the Content Manager.